# How to turn a string of letters into 3 letter words in Python 2.7.1

Tags: python, string, list, function, cpu-word

I have a string of letters '`aaabbbcccdddeeefffggg`' that i would like to read as 3 letter words. For example, `'aaa','bbb','ccc'...`

Is there any code that you know of that can do this function?

My ultimate goal is to assign numbers to each word like

```
aaa= 123
bbb= 234
ccc= 356 ...
```

and have the output be the position of the word in the sentence with that value

so for the sentence of '`aaabbbcccdddeeefffggg`'
the three letter words would be `'aaa','bbb','ccc'...`

`aaa` would be the 1st position (1), `bbb` would be the 2nd position (2), `ccc` would be the 3rd position (3)

so ultimately i would get

```
(1,123),(2,234),(3,356) for 'aaa','bbb','ccc'
```

i have been trying this for a few hours and i cannot figure out how to do this so any help would be much appreciated

thanks

Comment: How do you assign numbers to words? A dictionary?

Comment: If this isn't a dictionary the question is I guess what comes after `ggg = 789`

Comment: The question is not clear.  
What should be result for "aabbbcdddefg"?
[aab, bbc, ddd, efg]
OR
[bbb, ddd]

Comment: No this isn't homework.  The result for "aabbbcdddefg" should be simply [bbb,ddd] b/c those were the only ones assigned.  I figure out how to split into 3 letter words and assign those words values, but my problem now is to have a random sequence like your "aabbbcdddefg" and (since bbb and ddd were assigned the values 234 and 567) spit out '234','567'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> a = "aaabbbcccdddeeefffggg"
>>> [a[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(a), 3)]
['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee', 'fff', 'ggg']
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
data = 'aaabbbcccdddeeefffggg'
trans = {'aaa': 123, 'bbb': 234, 'ccc': 356, ...}
[(x + 1, trans[y * 3]) for x, y in enumerate(data[::3])]
```

Otherwise:

```
def trans(c):
    a = ord('a')
    return ord(c) - a + 3 + 10 * (ord(c) - a + 2) + 100 * (ord(c) - a + 1)

data = 'aaabbbcccdddeeefffggg'
[(x + 1, trans(y)) for x, y in enumerate(data[::3])]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(".{3}" ,"aaabbbcccdddeeefffggg")
['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee', 'fff', 'ggg']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ch = 'bbbiiieeefffhhhaaacccddd'

d = dict(zip(('aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd','eee','fff','ggg','hhh','iii'),
             ('123','234','345','456','567','678','789','8910','91011')))

def lect(x):
    gen = iter(x) 
    while True:
        yield ''.join((gen.next(),gen.next(),gen.next()))

print [ (i+1,d[x]) for i,x in enumerate(lect(ch)) ]
```

or

```
import re

ch = 'bbbiiieeefffhhhaaacccddd'

d = dict(zip(('aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd','eee','fff','ggg','hhh','iii'),
             ('123','234','345','456','567','678','789','8910','91011')))

pat = re.compile('|'.join(d.iterkeys()))

print [ ((mat.start()/3)+1,d[mat.group()]) for mat in pat.finditer(ch) ]
```